# Migrating Gerrit and Git repos to new server

Tags: git, gerrit

I am planning to migrate gerrit to another new machine along with git repositories.

My git repos are present in `GERRIT/git` directory.

Is it just okay to move the entire installation folder of gerrit will be enough?

Could some one help me with detailed steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the Gerrit installation folder AND do not forget to also consider the Gerrit database (I don't know if it is in the same machine or in a different one).

Check these other items too:

- Any software you have installed in Gerrit server (like Git, Java, Perl, Puppet, Nginx, Apache, MySQL, scripts in some "bin" directory, etc).
- Any references to paths that will change in the new machine (like /home/user => /disk0/user).
- /etc/init.d/gerrit configuration
- Nginx or Apache configuration
- Network/Firewall configurations